# How to split a column content using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

My source data is stored as (000000000000054390-) which denotes -543.90 I need the destination as -543.90. How this can be done using SSIS?

Thanks 
Arif

Answer (score 1):

Use a Derived Column object in your Data Flow Task.

You can then do a SUBSTRING (assuming that this is a string) manipulation on your number, which can in turn be cast into its proper data type.